# How to revalidate data on react-modal close with SWR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-modal, swr

I am trying to `revalidate` the data on [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) close using SWR in a NextJS project.

I am using the `SWR` hook like so.

```js
  const { data, error, isValidating } = useSWR(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL + `/api/users`,
    fetcher,{
    revalidateIfStale: true,
    revalidateOnFocus: true,
    revalidateOnMount:true, 
   }
  );


  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setUsers(data.users);
    }
  }, [data, isValidating, users]);

//handle loading..
//handle error..


  return (
    <main className="mx-auto max-w-7xl ">
      <Header title="All users"/>
      <UsersList users={users} />
    </main>
  );
```

I am fetching a list of users and displaying them.

```js
  const usersList = users.((user) => (
    <div className="space-x-5 text-sm" key={user.id}>
      {user.name}
      <DisableModal id={user.id} isDisabled={user.active}/>
    </div>
  ));
```

I have a react modal that allows us to disable the users, once I have disabled the users with handle click.

When the modal closes the data is not being refetched.
This is a sample modal from the docs.

When I close the modal, and can see the list of users. They are not refreshed and not using revalidations with use SWR.

```js
export const DisableModal = ({
  id,
  isDisabled,
}) => {
  const [disableModalIsOpen, setDisableModalIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function closeDisableModal() {
    setDisableModalIsOpen(false);
  }

  function openPublishModal() {
    setDisableModalIsOpen(true);
  }

  const handleDisableUser = async () => {
  //disable logic in rest call.
   closeDisableModal();
  }
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revalidate the data manually using [`mutate`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#revalidate) when the `onAfterClose` callback in the modal gets triggered.

```js
export const DisableModal = () => {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
    const { mutate } = useSWRConfig()

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => { setShowModal(true) }}>Trigger Modal</button>
            <ReactModal 
                isOpen={showModal}
                onAfterClose={() => { 
                    mutate(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL + '/api/users') 
                }}
                contentLabel="Minimal Modal Example"
            >
                <button onClick={() => { setShowModal(false) }}>Close Modal</button>
            </ReactModal>
        </>
    )
}
```

Calling `mutate(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL + '/api/users')` will broadcast a revalidation message to SWR hook with that given key. Meaning the `useSWR(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL + '/api/users', fetcher, { ... })` hook will re-run and return the updated users data.